# Why is one thread getting activated in my Producer Consumer Code

Tags: java, multithreading, locks

I am learning locks and conditions in Java and have implemented producer and consumer code.Idea is to have 1 producer and N Consumer . But when i run the code , always 1 consumer thread read

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Queue;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.Condition;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.Lock;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;

public class ProdConsumer {
    int MAX_ELEMENTS = 10;
    Queue<Integer> q ;
    Lock lock =  new ReentrantLock(false);
    Condition read  =  lock.newCondition();
    Condition write = lock.newCondition();

    ProdConsumer(){
        q = new LinkedList<>();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        ProdConsumer pq  = new ProdConsumer();
        new Thread(() -> {
            try {
                new Producer(pq.q).produce(pq.lock,pq.read,pq.write,pq.MAX_ELEMENTS);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }).start();

        new Thread(() -> {
            try {
                System.out.println("Started " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
                new Consumer(pq.q).consume(pq.lock,pq.read,pq.write);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }).start();

        new Thread(() -> {
            try {
                System.out.println("Started " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
                new Consumer(pq.q).consume(pq.lock,pq.read,pq.write);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }).start();
    }

}

class Producer {
    Queue q;

    Producer(Queue q) {
        this.q = q;
    }

    void produce(Lock lock, Condition read, Condition write, int MAX_ELEMENTS) throws InterruptedException {
        lock.lock();
        try {
            int count = 0;
            while (count < 1000) {
                while (q.size() == MAX_ELEMENTS) {
                    write.await();
                }
                q.add(count);
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + "PRODUCED " + count);
                count++;
                read.signalAll();
            }
        } finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }
}

class Consumer {
    Queue q;
    Consumer(Queue q ){
        this.q = q;
    }
    void consume(Lock lock, Condition read, Condition write) throws InterruptedException {
        lock.lock();
        try {
            while (true) {
                while (q.size() == 0) {
                    read.await();
                }
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + "CONSUMED " + q.poll());
                Thread.sleep((long)(Math.random() * 1000));
                write.signalAll();
            }
        } finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }
}
```

Result:

```
Started Thread-1
Started Thread-2
Thread-0PRODUCED 0
Thread-0PRODUCED 1
Thread-0PRODUCED 2
Thread-0PRODUCED 3
Thread-0PRODUCED 4
Thread-0PRODUCED 5
Thread-0PRODUCED 6
Thread-0PRODUCED 7
Thread-0PRODUCED 8
Thread-0PRODUCED 9
Thread-1CONSUMED 0
Thread-1CONSUMED 1
Thread-1CONSUMED 2
Thread-1CONSUMED 3
Thread-1CONSUMED 4
Thread-1CONSUMED 5
Thread-1CONSUMED 6
Thread-1CONSUMED 7
Thread-1CONSUMED 8
Thread-1CONSUMED 9
```

Here we can see , even tough both thread starts , always Thread one is consuming.
My thought process is , when producer signals all , then either of consumer thread should start. What am i doing wrong ?

Comment: Try unlocking the `lock()` when the consumer calls `Thread.sleep(...)`. When you design a program with locks, your goal should be to only keep them locked for the least possible amount of time. (e.g., just long enough to take something from a queue, or just long enough to post a result to some collection.) You want to design your threads so that most of the work they do is _unlocked._ If all of the work that they do is locked, then what even is the point of using threads? Only one of them will be able to do any work at any given moment in time.

Comment: Wont singnall() do an unlock  ? I assumption is when i do signall all , the thread will discard it ownership , i.e suspend , and then someone else can takeover

Comment: Re, "Wont singnall() do an unlock." No. It doesn't do that. You have to do it explicitly. https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/locks/Condition.html#signal()

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you have implemented the producer-consumer with a dependency on both the queue size and locks, and the queue access is not thread-safe. The implementation is unlikely to work properly as producer could call `signalAll` several times when neither consumer is using `read`.

Because your producer starts first it could either add the queue so that both consumers see `q.size() > 0` when they start-up or they might both see `q.size() == 0` and miss the producer saying `read.signalAll()` before they enter `read.await()`. Thus this while loop below is not doing as you expect in both consumers:

```
while (q.size() == 0) {
    read.await();
}
```

To demonstrate the above, switch the new Threads around and start up both `Consumer` first BEFORE the `Producer`, and change the consumer so they rely only on only the `read` locks not queue size to determine when to read the queue.

```
//  while (q.size() == 0) {
    read.await();
//  }
```

That avoids not-threadsafe access to `q.size()` and `q.poll()` but still may fail if both consumers do not hit `read.await()` so you might need to sleep before starting the producer.

A better (and reliable) solution would replace locks with thread-safe Queue such as `new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(MAX_ELEMENTS)` and use `q.put()` / `q.take()` to ensure consumers are exactly handling everything from the producer, and then you won't need to worry about the order of producer-consumer startup (nor add a sleep before producer start-up).

Also note that `System.out` in these threads introduces some inter-thread synchronisation (see `PrintWriter` source code) so the results may not be same without your logging.